# Error when using a multilevel regression (lme4)

Tags: r, error-handling, regression, lme4, multilevel-analysis

I want to use a multilevel regression to analyse the effect of some independent variables on a dependent variable and use varying intercept and slope.

My regression includes non-numeric independent variables which I want to use for the varying intercept and slope. The dependent variable is a numeric variable. When using this multilevel regression I get the following error:

> Error: number of observations (=88594) <= number of random effects (=337477) for term (1 + x | z); the random-effects parameters and the residual variance (or scale parameter) are probably unidentifiable

`x` and `z` are characters and are correlated with each other and with `y`. This is the regression I use:

```r
multi_reg1 <- lmer(y~ 1 + x + (1 + x| z), REML = FALSE, data = data_frame1)
```

Is there a way to fix this problem or is it not possible and I have to use other regression methods?

Comment: How many levels (unique values) do `x` and `z` have? It's possible to override this error (see `?lmerControl`), but before you do that you should think carefully about whether the model you're trying to fit is actually identifiable.

Comment: I think the number of unique values is the problem as x = 233 and z = 1303. 
I am not sure if the multilevel model is the best approach but I want to figure out the impact of x and z on y. When using a linear regression the result is biased due to the high number of unique values of z. 
(The aim of my analysis is to find the drivers of y.)